# Make a fixed position element appear behind a static position element

Tags: css, z-index

How can you make an element that has a `position: fixed` display behind an element with `position: static`? Changing z-index doesn't seem to matter since they are not absolute.

Comment: make your static element as `position: relative`. if you don't have any `absolute` children within it, your UI won't change at all, and you can manage desired element with `z-index`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use negative z-index on the fixed element.

```
<div id="fixed">This is fixed</div>
<div id="static">This is static</div>

#fixed {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/rcthewkk/)**

Comment: when i give the element z-index: -1, it is no longer clickable. Any ideas?

Comment: It's because now it's behind the static element so the static element will receive the click instead.

Comment: Note that Ken Fyrstenberg's solution works **only** with `#static{position: relative;}`